# Querying execution status of Durable Function from Azure Static Web App returns 400 - Bad Request

Tags: c#, reactjs, azure, azure-functions, azure-static-web-app

I have a React app that is hosted as a Static Web App on Azure.

The frontend is linked to a Durable Function App that provides some endpoints as the Web Apps backend.

Since the workflows executed in the Function App are long running, I decided to implement the Async HTTP API pattern, so that the Static Web App can query the status of the function execution, instead of showing the error `Backend Call Failed` after the default period of 45 seconds (which currently can not be adjusted).

Here is the code snippet for my React App:

```
let response = await this.api.post('/myEndpoint', JSON.stringify(myRequestData));

//Check if the initial request was successful
if (response.status === 400) {
        const myCustomResponse= this.CreateFailureResponse(response);
        return myCustomResponse;
      }

//Get query url
const pollingUrl = response.data.statusQueryGetUri;
const timer = (ms:number):unknown => new Promise((res) => setTimeout(res, ms));

//Poll Url until HTTP Status Code is != 202
while (response.status === 202) {
    /* eslint-disable no-await-in-loop */
    await timer(5000);
    /* eslint-disable no-await-in-loop */
    response = await this.api.get(pollingUrl , { timeout: 5000 });
}

//Check if execution threw an exception
if (response.status !== 200) {
    const myCustomResponse= this.CreateFailureResponse(response);
    return myCustomResponse;
}

//Create SuccessResponse with success message shown to the user
const myCustomResponse= this.CreateSuccessResponse(response);

return myCustomResponse;
```

And here is the client code of the Durable Function App:

```
[FunctionName(nameof(myFunction))]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> HttpStart(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post")] HttpRequestMessage req,
        [DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient starter)
    {
        var errorResponse = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        if (req?.Content is null)
        {
            errorResponse.Content = new StringContent("Could not process request due to missing content.");
            return errorResponse;
        }

        var requestContent = await req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var myCustomRequest= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyCustomRequest>(requestContent);
        var validationResult = await _requestValidator.ValidateAsync(myCustomRequest);
        if (!validationResult.IsValid)
        {
            errorResponse.Content = new StringContent($"The request contained the following errors:\r{string.Join("\r", validationResult.Errors)}");
            return errorResponse;
        }

        var instanceId = await starter.StartNewAsync(nameof(MyOrchestrator), myCustomRequest);
        return starter.CreateCheckStatusResponse(req, instanceId, returnInternalServerErrorOnFailure: true);
    }
```

At the first try I received the following error when the React App tried to query the status endpoint returned by the Function App:

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://myfunctionapp.azurewebsites.net/runtime/webhooks/durabletask/instances/123456?taskHub=myfunctionapp&connection=Storage&code=someCode==&returnInternalServerErrorOnFailure=true' from origin 'https://mywebapp.azurestaticapps.net' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

So I configured CORS on my Function App:
[image: CORS configuration]

The problem now is, that even though I enabled CORS, I still can not successfully acces the URL to query the status of the Durable Function execution.

After configuring CORS, I received the following error:
`GET https://myfunctionapp.azurewebsites.net/runtime/webhooks/durabletask/instances/12345?taskHub=myfunctionapp&connection=Storage&code=someCode&returnInternalServerErrorOnFailure=true 400 (Bad Request)`

I assume this might be due to an authorization problem, because when I remove the authentication provider from my Azure Function App (which is added automatically when linking it to a Static Web App to prevent requests from outside the Web App) it works.
But I can't figure out the exact problem.

On my local machine it works totally fine.

Sorry for the pretty long post and thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you confirm the values for the `taskHub` and `connection` are correct even for your instance on Azure?

Comment: I suggest they are, because the `statusQueryGetUri` ist returned by the Function App by calling `CreateCheckStatusResponse()` on the `IDurableOrchestrationClient` instance.
If I remove the identity provider from the "Authentication" area in the Azure Portal, it works as expected and the values for `taskHub` and `connection` stay unchanged.

Comment: @PramodValavala do you have any further advices on this?